# 2007 Acura RDX (base) key wont turn to LOCK (0) position

Tags: acura

I own a 2007 Acura RDX (base) with 103k miles.. When I parked my car at work today, I couldn't remove the key - the key would push in but I cannot turn it to the LOCK (0) position. At lunch, I ran to Lowe's for lock lube and a screwdriver, since I didn't have one in the car, and remove the plastic surrounding the column. When I removed the bottom part, I don't recall exactly what I did but the pressure I put on the key allowed the key to turn to lock and I was able to pull it out real quick.. however, the key is now stuck again.. I cleaned it but I had to get back to work. Here are some more details:

- I can hear "clicks" when moving the shifter to different gears
- When in (P)ark, the doors unlock (as programmed) and the instrument panel lights up (P)
- The battery in the key has been dead for sometime because the actuator in the driver's side door broke a few years ago.. no big deal 2+ years
- The car starts without issue
- When I turn the car to "ON" the green "D" lights up as well as the red "P" (or whatever gear I am in) I do not know if this is normal

Any help would be appreciated and if there is a way to override the lock so my battery won't die just to get through the weekend that would be great to know.